# Are PowerShell objects returned from a remote session different?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a C# application that queries Lync and Exchange PowerShell using Runspaces. If I execute the application on a server that has local access to the PowerShell commandlets i.e. the management tools are installed, it works; however, if I connect to the server remotely, my foreach logic fails with the following error:

[image: Foreach loop error]

Example loop - the first loop works fine, however it fails at the 2nd one as I drill down in the PS objects:

```
public Collection<PSObject> Workflows;


var wFFilter = _dataService.WorkFlows.ToList();

//foreach (PSObject workflowName in workflowNames)
foreach (dynamic workflowName in wFFilter)
{
    var newWorkflow = new WorkFlowViewModel();
    if (workflowName != null)
    {
        //GetDisplay Name
        newWorkflow.Name = workflowName.Name;

        //Populate IVR options
        foreach (dynamic root in workflowName.DefaultAction.Question.AnswerList)
        {
            if (root.Action.QueueID != null)
            {
                //Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This leads me to believe there is something different in the way the PowerShell object is returned. Could this be the case? I just cant figure out why this is different, and how I can handle both local and remotely returned objects.

My PS code:

```
private RunspacePool rrp;
public Collection<PSObject> ExecuteSynchronously(string PSCommand, string     RemoteMachineFqdn, int RemoteMachinePort, string RemoteMachinePath,
       bool SslEnabled, string Username, SecureString Password)
    {
        Collection<PSObject> psResult;

        if (rrp == null)
        {
            string shellUri = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";
            PSCredential remoteCredential = new PSCredential(Username, Password);
            WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(SslEnabled, RemoteMachineFqdn,
                RemoteMachinePort, RemoteMachinePath, shellUri, remoteCredential);

            connectionInfo.SkipRevocationCheck = true;
            connectionInfo.SkipCACheck = true;
            connectionInfo.SkipCNCheck = true;

            rrp = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspacePool(1, 10, connectionInfo);
            rrp.Open();
        }

        using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powershell.RunspacePool = rrp;
            powershell.AddScript(PSCommand);
            psResult = powershell.Invoke();
        }
        return psResult;

    }
```

Thanks! Really appreciate some help on this :)

Comment: Remote objects have to be serialized/deserialized to be delivered to local session. Given your quite long property path, I can guess, that you hit at default serialization depth limit.

Comment: Do you know of any way around this so that I can receive the full object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The are different because they've been serialized at the remote session and then deserialized in your local session.  Serialization can result in loss of fidelity of object properties, and removal of methods from the objects.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - is there anyway to stop this behavior so that I can handle both local and remotely returned PSObjects using my code?

Comment: I can't really answer that. I'm not fluent in C#, but am very familiar with the differences between native objects returned in an EMS shell and the deserialized objects returned by an implicit remoting session when doing Exchange management.

Comment: Hi @AndrewMorpeth. I'm having the same problem: did you have a solution?

Comment: Not really a solution but I built the app with the requirement of the PowerShell management tools being installed locally. Basically, it's a serialization problem and it affects deeply nested objects. I could access top-level nested objects but only to a certain level. To remove the requirement for the management tools to be installed locally I suggest you run in a server/client model with an agent running on the remote server to execute your commands on behalf of the client. Hope that helps.